# How to validate a name in Python?

Tags: python, validation

I need to validate a name input where the code makes sure that the user doesn't input any random characters as well as numbers for their reply to their name. So far I tried using a `.isdigit()` command however that didn't allow the user to re try entering their name.

```
name = input("\nWhat Is Your Name? : ") 

if name.isdigit():
    print ("Invalid!") 
    name = input("\nWhat Is Your Name? : ")
    continue
else :
    print("\nHi {}! Welcome to the Arithmetic quiz!".format(name))
```

Comment: so the name should not contain any numbers

Comment: It seems there are two questions: 1) how to check if the input string is a valid name (.isalpha() ?) and 2) how to repeat the user prompt until the input is valid.

Comment: @VigneshKalai Yes, thats the goal

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. You can have it dissociated from your account, if you want - flag for moderator attention, ask for dissociation and give a good reason why you want the dissociation.

Answer (score 3):

Continue only works in loops, but here is a working loop for you that does what you want:

```
while True:
   name = input("\nWhat Is Your Name? : ")
   if not name.isalpha():
       print ("Invalid!") 
   else:
        break    

print("\nHi {}! Welcome to the Arithmetic quiz!".format(name))
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain the reason behind the 'While True' line being there? @gkusner

Comment: @MysticMods ` while loop ` loops until the condition given is false in this case `while True` it goes on looping since the condition never fails it keeps on looping .So at this condition it will only break the loop if a `break` statement is met which is met in the else case so `while  True in this case will loop until the given name is valid`

Comment: Sorry I missed the question but Vignesh Kalai nailed the explanation.

Comment: @VigneshKalai Kalai  Thanks, Now i understand, Anyways thanks for the reply and thanks for your Help ...

Comment: @MysticMods if this answer solved your question accept it if not then comment what is wrong :) and happy to help